# How large is the smallest ordinal larger than any “minimal ordinal parameter” for any pair of an Ordinal Turing Machine and a real?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, ordinal-numbers

In this question, the notation $P^x(\alpha)$ denotes a situation where a particular [OTM-program](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502264) $P$ performs a computation on input $x$ with an ordinal parameter $\alpha$, assuming that $x$ is written on the initial segment of length $\omega$ (the smallest limit ordinal) of the tape of $P$ at time $0$. That is, $x$ is the input for $P$ written in cells indexed by finite ordinals $(0, 1, 2, \ldots)$ before the start of computation, yet all cells indexed by all ordinals greater than or equal to $\omega$ are initially blank, except one cell indexed by $\alpha$ (this cell is marked by a non-zero symbol.)

Let $\beta$ denote *the smallest* ordinal such that for *any* pair of an OTM-program $P$ and a real $x$ (that is, $P$ quantifies over *all* programs and $x$ quantifies over *all* reals) exactly one of the following statements is true:

1. There does not exist an (uncountable or countable) ordinal $\alpha$ such that $P^x(\alpha)$ halts;
2. If there exists at least one (uncountable or countable) ordinal $\alpha$ such that $P^x(\alpha)$ halts, then, assuming that $\alpha_0$ is the smallest such ordinal, $\alpha_0 < \beta.$

How large is $\beta$?

Comment: So your question is what is the least non-OTM-computable with a real parameter, am I correct?

Comment: @HanulJeon I didn't understand the question. Regarding what you wrote (just to be sure) did you mean: "what is the least non-OTM-computable ordinal with any arbitrary real parameter allowed"? Admittedly, I don't understand the second part of your answer though (w.r.t. upper-bound). For V=L, my personal reasoning goes as follows: Given any arbitrary ordinal parameters less than a countable $\alpha$ the sup of values clocked (with parameters $< \alpha$) can be shown to be countable. And hence the upper-bound follows (because any real can be computed with some countable ordinal parameter).

Comment: @SSequence: "I didn't understand the question" — can you please specify which part of the question is unclear?

Comment: @SSequence: "You could just have $\omega$ as a parameter and a certain machine would halt regardless of what real input was placed on it" — yes, of course, a particular program $P_1$ will halt. But a particular program $P_2$ will not (with the same input.) I have emphasized that we take into account _all_ programs, _all_ inputs and _all_ ordinal parameters (assuming that the parameter is _minimal_, as is written in the question).

Comment: @SSequence: [1/2]: yes, of course, but these facts do not affect the definition of $\beta$ at all. Consider the following game. I pick an arbitrary ordinal $\tau_0$. You pick an arbitrary OTM $P$ and an arbitrary real $x$, then write $x$ on the cells indexed by finite ordinals.

Comment: @SSequence: [2/2]: If there exists an ordinal $\tau_1 \geq \tau_0$ such that $P^x$ halts if and only if you write "1" in the $\tau_1$-th cell and does not halt if _any_ ordinal parameter less than $\tau_0$ is used, you win. Does there exist an ordinal such that I always win, no matter which pair of $P$ and $x$ you choose? If yes, then $\beta$ is the smallest such always-winning ordinal. If no, I need an explanation.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I think I get what you are saying. For V=L, the answer is still $\omega_1$ (for reasons very similar to mentioned in second comment). Given the answer by by Hanul Jeon, it seems that the answer is $\omega_1$ in general too.

Comment: Here is your question as I understand it. You mean $P^x(\alpha)$ to denote a real number $x$ in first $\omega$ cells and a single $1$ at the position $\alpha \geq \omega$. And you are asking for the smallest ordinal $\beta$ (if it exists) such that for all possible choices for programs $P$ and real numbers $x$, one of the following is true: $(1)$ The smallest ordinal $\alpha_0$ such that $P^x(\alpha_0)$ halts is less than $\beta$. $(2)$ There exists no ordinal $\alpha \in Ord$ such that $P^x(\alpha)$ halts.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I am deleting some of my previous comments (before your comments about the game) as they make the discussion harder to follow. You might also delete some of your comments (before that point) if you want to.

Comment: @SSequence: yes, the interpretation above is correct (assuming that $\alpha$ is _allowed_ to be uncountable.) I know that $0^{\sharp}$ is _recognizable_ from $\omega_1$, if $0^{\sharp}$ exists, but it is not recognizable from any countable ordinal. Can the existence of such reals affect the answer to the question?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is allowed to be any ordinal. I do not know the fully general answer. The interpretation written in the answer seems to be fairly close to what you have written. So unless that small difference in interpretation changes the answer, the general also seems to be $\omega_1$ (based on the given answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is disputation on how to interpret the problem, I think it would be better to clarify my interpretation:

> Let $P(x,\alpha)$ be a program, which takes a binary sequence $x\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ (also called a real, which is standard terminology in set theory) and an ordinal $\alpha$. Consider the set
> $$H = \{\alpha\mid \text{$\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that $P(x,\alpha) $ halts for some $x$, $P$} \}.$$
> Then $H$ is a set. What is the value of $\sup H$?

If I understand your problem correctly, then the answer is $\omega_1$. Please feel free to comment if there is an error in my proof.

---

For the lower bound, we will find an OTM-program with a parameter $x\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ that computes a countable ordinal. Assume that $x$ codes a well-order over $\omega$ whose order-type is $\alpha$. Consider the following procedure: decode $x$ and enumerate ordinals less than the order-type of $x$ by brute force. (This is possible since there are only countably many members in $x$ and we have infinite time.) In this way, we can compute $\alpha$ from $x$. Now take $P(\beta)$ as follows: if $\beta=\alpha$, it halts. If not, it does not halt.

For the upper bound, assume that we have a program $P$ of real parameter $x$. By Lemma 2.6 of Koepke's *Turing Computations on Ordinals*, the ordinal computation by $P$ is absolute between $V$ and $L[x]$. Assume that $P$ halts with an input $\alpha_0$, and $\alpha_0$ is the *smallest* such an ordinal. Moreover, assume that we take time $\theta$ to compute $P(\alpha_0)$.

Now consider the Skolem hull $M$ of sufficiently large $L_\gamma[x]$ generated by $\{\theta,\alpha_0,x\}$. By condensation, there is an isomorphism $\pi:M\to L_\beta[x]$ for some countable $\beta$. Then $L_\beta[x]$ thinks $P$ halts with an input $\pi(\alpha_0)$ and does not halt if we plug in ordinals smaller than $\pi(\alpha_0)$.
By $\pi(\alpha_0)\le \alpha_0$, Lemma 2.6 of Koepke and minimality of $\alpha_0$, we have $\pi(\alpha_0)=\alpha_0$. Hence $\alpha_0$ is countable.

Comment: [1/2]: I am not sure what you mean by "real parameter $x$" and why you wrote "$x$ codes a well-order" and "$P$ halts with an input $\alpha_0$", so in order to avoid ambiguity, I have to clarify that $x$ is not a parameter, $x$ is an input: it is an arbitrary real (the word "real" here implies an infinite binary sequence) written on all cells indexed by natural numbers. Note that since $x$ is arbitrary, it is not required to code a well-order.

Comment: [2/2]: Then $\alpha_0$ is not an input, it is always the smallest ordinal greater than or equal to $\omega$ such that a program $P$ halts given $x$ as the input and a single "1" written on the $\alpha_0$-th cell of the tape. Do these clarifications affect the answer?

Comment: @lyricallywicked The second half of your question is difficult to understand. You don't seem to specify any relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in your possibilities-(1),(2) in the second half of your question. The answer given is for the following question: "what is the least ordinal not reachable by any OTM (with no ordinal parameters and any arbitrary real input allowed)".

Comment: @SSequence: [1/2] "You don't seem to specify any relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in your possibilities-(1),(2)" — why? I have provided the full definition. If there exists at least one _ordinal parameter_ such that an arbitrary OTM halts with $\alpha$ as the parameter and $x$ as the input, then there is the smallest such parameter, denoted by $\alpha_0$. Then $\beta$ is the smallest ordinal greater than any $\alpha_0$ under the assumption that $x$ is _an arbitrary real_.

Comment: @SSequence: [2/2] Regarding [The answer given is for the following question: "what is the least ordinal not reachable by any OTM (with no ordinal parameters and any arbitrary real input allowed)"] — if this is so, then no, this is not what this question is about. Definition of $\beta$ is not related to being (non-)reachable, (non-)computable or  (non-)writable. It is related to _ordinal parameters_. Note that ordinal parameters for OTMs may be uncountable (for example, $0^{\sharp}$ is recognizable from $\omega_1$, if $0^{\sharp}$ exists, but it is not recognizable from any countable ordinal.)

Comment: @lyricallywicked I use the term 'a real parameter' for an input $x\subseteq \omega$, coded by a binary sequence of length $\omega$. I do not think the answer is changed even if $x$ is arbitrary (just take $x$ that codes a well-order of a given countable ordinal, we can make this choice as $x$ is *arbitrary*.)

Comment: I also know that $\alpha_0$ is not an input. My first part of the proof suggests there is a program $P$ such that if we put an appropriate binary sequence $x$, then $P(\alpha)$ halts but $P(\xi)$ does not halt for $\xi\neq\alpha$.

Comment: @lyricallywicked It would be better to give my interpretation of your problem in my answer. Could you check that I am correct?

Comment: @HanulJeon: Regarding "Let $P(x, \alpha)$ be a program, which takes a real $x$ and an ordinal $\alpha$" — I am still not sure what you mean by "a program takes an ordinal". The real $x$ is written on the cells indexed by natural numbers, then, additionally, a single "1" is written on the $\alpha$-th cell. All other cells are blank. If this is what you mean, this interpretation is correct. Regarding the definition of the set $H$ — if it takes all pairs of $P$ and $x$ into account, this interpretation is correct.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I meant a code of an ordinal a la Koepke: he coded ordinals to a binary sequence with a single 1. Since we are working with an ordinal greater than $\alpha$, we may replace $(x,\alpha)$ to a single binary sequence, which codes $x$ for the first $\omega$ cells and a single 1 at the $\alpha$th cell.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I mean the transfinite binary sequence (i.e., binary seqeuence of arbitrary ordinal length.) Sorry for possibly confusing terminology.

Comment: @HanulJeon: If "the transfinite binary sequence" means "the entire contents of the tape", the interpretation is correct. The reason of my confusion was that I thought that "a single binary sequence" implies a real whose bits are indexed by natural numbers.